# Irregular label on Excel chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel chart with months on its x-axis. The first date is December 2016 and the last date is November 2020. I need these two dates to be seen,
but I can't have all the labels being seen (it's too much information, looks messy).

**How can I display both those dates without having them all being shown?**

Answer (score 0):

It might have helped if you had said a bit more about what you were doing,
so I guessed that it was something simple. 
Try inserting a new column to the right of the “x” (date) column
and filling it with a formula like

```
=IF(OR(ROW()=1,ROW()=12), A1, "")
```

Then insert your chart starting with the new column.

[image: chart showing first and last “X” values]

Note that you can’t just click somewhere in your data
and insert your chart; you must explicitly select all your data
except for the original date column. 
For example, in the above illustration,
you would need to select `B1:C12` and then insert your chart.

Comment: I don't know why but your solution is not working for me. Excel does not consider the new column as the label (and instead labels every other month.)